# Jquery - add image at specific co-ordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to add a image at a clicked position within a div using jquery?

I need to develop a small game basically involves clicking the screen to guess a position - a image is placed wherever the user clicks...

I know how to get the X & Y coordinates of the place that was clicked - but have no idea how to place an image in that position...

Any help would be great-fully received!

Cheers
Paul

Comment: Simply add the new image right below the `<body` in the DOM and set it's `position` to `absolute` and set the position using `left` and `top`.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the div is set to `position: relative` then when you create your image make it `position:absolute` and set the `top` and `left` properties to your click coordinates. Something like this:

```
$('#yourdiv').append( 
  '<img src="/path/to/your/image.jpg" 
     style="width:auto;height:auto;position:absolute;
            left:' + yourxcoord + ';top:'+ yourycoord +'" />");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check a simple example from here http://jsfiddle.net/qA2jV/

jquery:

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    $(".foo").remove()
    $("body").append("<span class='foo'/>")
    $(".foo").css("left",e.pageX)
    $(".foo").css("top",e.pageY)
})
```

css:

```
.foo{
    background-image:url("https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/ym/r/9vuAQCVid3f.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    height:16px;
    width:16px;
}
```